# What dependencies should I load and to use the WP_Filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, wp-filesystem, wp-dependencies

I'm building a Wordpress theme which has a `WP_Filesystem` call in it:

```
<?php $wp_filesystem = new WP_Filesystem_Direct(null);
        echo $wp_filesystem->get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/images/Search_Glyph.svg'); ?>
```

I know that the `WP_Filesystem` needs some dependencies. I load them now like this in `functions.php`:

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to load the dependencies for the filesystem. I found an other [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/wp-filesystem-returns-null-what-are-the-dependencies) for plugin development and after some research I made the following code, which also works:

```
require_once ( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
WP_Filesystem();
```

What is the best way to load the dependencies for the `WP_Filesystem`? The first or the second code part? Or is there other code which I should use?

To me it seems the second, because `WP_Filesystem()` is a Wordpress function, but I don't know what it does exactly.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the best way to load the dependencies for the `WP_Filesystem`?
> The first or the second code part?

1. [`WP_Filesystem()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filesystem/) is used in conjunction with the global `$wp_filesystem` variable, so if you use it, then the second code part should be used.

   And `WP_Filesystem()` must be called so that the global `$wp_filesystem` variable is properly initialized/setup, i.e. assigned with the proper class instance or file system method (see [`get_filesystem_method()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_filesystem_method/), which defaults to [`WP_Filesystem_Direct`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_direct/)).
2. If you're not using the global `$wp_filesystem` variable, then you could just use the first one to manually load the dependencies which are loaded automatically by `WP_Filesystem()`.

Example using the global `$wp_filesystem` variable:

```php
global $wp_filesystem;

// Make sure that the above variable is properly setup.
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
WP_Filesystem();

// Check whether a file/directory exists.
$exists = $wp_filesystem->exists( '/some/path/here' );
var_dump( $exists );

// Get file content.
$data = $wp_filesystem->get_contents( 'path/to/file' );
var_dump( $data );
```

Example using a custom variable:

```php
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';

$filesystem = new WP_Filesystem_Direct( false );

var_dump( $filesystem->exists( '/some/path/here' ) );
```

Comment: Hi Sally, thank you again for your clear explanation!